# Can Clr2 Winform host Clr4 WPF or another mechanism?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, .net-remoting

Is there any way that Winform control in .NET3.5 CLR2 can use WPF control in .NET4.x CLR4? We would like to REUSE everything in WPF side including (UI, business logic and etc).

So far what I know is CLR2 can call CLR4 method by using .NET remoting. My company did something by using WCF, HwndSourceParameters and etc between these 2 CLR (very complicated)

[image]

Comment: You can host WPF elements in winform and vice versa. Note that you are talking about compiling, on runtime, its the same process, what happen if you want to use the winform control from another process in run time (lets say you consume API that return winform but want to host it in your WPF) ? its possible also, you need to send the hwnd pointer and create the object.

Comment: hi @ilansch, you are right and have stated the point. Sorry for confusing, it's really not about WinForm or WPF, but how the CLR2 and CLR4 work together. If not mistaken, my current company implementation is just liked what you said, create the CLR4 UI object and then in CLR2 use the hwnd to obtain the CLR4 UI object

Comment: so what is the problem ? what is not working ? what you are trying to do is do-able (hosting a winform hwnd pointer in a WPF application, the opposite, will probably not work)

Comment: Hi @ilansch, I just wondering if there any solutions other than this? I feel this integration very complexing and hard to maintain

Comment: This is what I did, nothing was complex and hard to maintain, get the hwnd from WinForm Control, send it as IntPtr32 over WCF between your CLR2 to CLR4 processes, Construct the same object on the CLR4 and use the pointers you sent.

Comment: Thanks, @ilansch! definitely will prototype it for personal learning